# Why is the size of two variables in the below code different?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  short i = 90L;
  long j = 90;
  printf("%d", sizeof(i));
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(j));
  return 0;
}
```

I just read that if we place L at the end of an integer value ,then actually it gets the storage equal to the long value ,so basically what do they mean by saying this ,as when I calculated the size of both the variables,it was different,had it been like it is actually occupying the size of a long variable ,then obviously it would have shown the size to be 4 bytes ,but it showed the size according to the size of a short data type only,so what is the reason behind it.

Is the value trunctated but then when I priint the value of i ,it prints it to be 90 only ,so how does everything take place.

Comment: The type of the *object* `i` is `short` - that doesn't change, regardless of the size of the value you assign to it.

Comment: If you are new to C then you should take a step back. It will take you a while until you find an example where you need `sizeof`. Probably your teacher is to blame for giving you bad code examples. For now I can tell you that you should refrain from using `short` and `long`. Use `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64` and their unsigned counterparts if the width of the variable matters.

Comment: The result of `sizeof` is of type `size_t`. Use `"%zu"`, not `"%d"`, to print it.

Comment: @Kay: Using the exact-width types makes sense only if you need a specific exact width. If you need an integer type that's at least 16 bits and fairly small, `short` makes sense. If you need something that's at least 32 bits, `long` makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

```
short i=90L;
```

`90L` is a constant of type `long`. The initialization converts that value to `short`.

```
long j=90;
```

`90` is a constant of type `int`. The initialization converts it to type `long`.

The size of an object (variable) has nothing to do with its current value. It's the number of bytes it occupies in memory.

Comment: And very importantly, `90L` doesn't have storage as implied by the OP. It doesn't reside in any data section, only as part of the `mov` opcode in the executable code itself.

Comment: @Blindy,Sir do you want to say that 90L does not occupy any memory ?

Comment: @RADHAGOGIA: There is no C object containing the `long` value `90L`. In the "abstract machine", the value is constructed in some unspecified manner, converted from `long` to `short`, and the result of the conversion is stored in `i`. In practice, the compiler almost certainly will not bother with the conversion and will generate code to store the value in `i`. It's likely to exist only in the instruction, or perhaps temporarily on a register.

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size
>   is determined from the type of the operand.**

So `sizeof( short )` that corresponds to `sizeof( i )` is less than `sizeof( long )` that corresponds of `sizeof( j )`.

The compiler cannot accomodate more data than it is allocated for a specified type.:)

Comment: Yes ,that I have understood but still the confusion prevails in mind that why is 90L not allocated memory and if no memory allocation takes place then how does the process of truncation takes place?

Comment: @RADHA GOGIA I have not understood how SQL is related to the code you showed.